# I need to open task pane automatically when worksheet loads or when we upload manifest

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, add-in

I am creating add-in of excel and I need to open task pane automatically so, How can I do that.

Also, I need to one solution like how we run js code in background without open the task pane.

I have also checked solution like below links but, that have not worked.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/run-code-on-document-open
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

Checked all the possible solutions also that gets from the other users but, that haven't works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You must provide more detail than "have not worked". What goes wrong and when?